# How do I make a cell take up two rows in longtable environment

Tags: pdftex

I hope it looks like this：

[image]

instead of that：
[image]

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\centering
\begin{longtable}{cccccccccccccc}
\endfirsthead
\caption{(countinue)}
\endhead
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\toprule 
No.   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Shock Start} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{MC Start} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{MC End} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Delta$t\newline{} (hr)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$V_{rad}$ \newline{} (km/s) } \\
\midrule
1  & 1998/05/01 21:22:45 & 1998/05/02 12:18:00 & 1998/05/03 17:18:00 & 29.0  & 517
\bottomrule
\midrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \newline{} doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a tabular. Unfortunately, your example was missing important ingredients. You may also consider using `siunitx` for the units, `makecell` and whatnot, but this is a simple way to address your question.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\centering
\begin{longtable}{cccccccccccccc}
\endfirsthead
\caption{(countinue)}
\endhead
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\toprule 
No.   & Shock Start & 
MC Start & MC End & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}$\Delta t$\\ (hr)
\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} $V_\mathrm{rad}$\\  (km/s) \end{tabular} \\
\midrule
1  & 1998/05/01 21:22:45 & 1998/05/02 12:18:00 & 1998/05/03 17:18:00 & 29.0  &
517\\
\bottomrule
\midrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, I solved the problem with your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a narrow `b{}`-column in combination with `\multicolumn`. Then the heading is (correctly) aligned at the bottom baseline. Use `p` or `m` if your typographical traditions recommends centred or top aligned headings.

I have defined a new column type `C` to reduce the clutter:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\centering
\begin{longtable}{cccccccccccccc}
\endfirsthead
\caption{(countinue)}
\endhead
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\toprule 
No.   & Shock Start & 
MC Start & MC End & \multicolumn{1}{P}{$\Delta t$ (hr)} & \multicolumn{1}{P}{$V_\mathrm{rad}$ (km/s)} \\
\midrule
1  & 1998/05/01 21:22:45 & 1998/05/02 12:18:00 & 1998/05/03 17:18:00 & 29.0  &
517\\
\bottomrule
\midrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a good way, thank u.

Comment: If you find the answer helpful, I apprieciate an upvote and, eventually, that you accept the answer.

Comment: I have upvoted. Since my reputation less than 15, the publicly displayed post score didnot be changed. Thanks again. @Sveinung